# How to downgrade gtk+ easy

Tags: gtk3, elementary

I have elementary os installed (based on ubuntu 12.04, gtk+ v.3.4.2). I upgraded to gtk+ 3.6.1 using PPA. After using it I found a lot of inconsistencies in the interface...

Can you help me to downgrade back to the gtk+ 3.4.2 without pain. At the moment if I try to do that via Synaptic it suggests to delete almost all the GTK-based software.

Thank you!